# How to create new file from two other csv files?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have two .csv files.

First:
col. names: `'student_id'` and `'mark'`

Second:
col. names: `'student_id'`,`'name'`,`'surname'`

and I want create third .csv file with `'student_id'`,`'name'`, `'surname'` where `row['mark'] == 'five'` or `'four'`

```
good_student=[]

for index, row in first_file.iterrows():
    if row['mark'] == 'five':
        good_student.append(row['studentId'])
    elif row['mark'] == 'four':
        good_student.append(row['studentId'])

for index, row in second_file.iterrows():
    for i in good_student:
        if row['studentId'] == i:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the other user suggested, a dataframe is a robust way of handling your csv problem. First, I would read the two csv files into dataframes using the`read_csv` function. Then I would join the two based on student id. The result is a dataframe w
ith columns as student_id, mark, name, and surname. Any missing values will be NaN (which dataframe the join is called on is important in handling missing values). The joined dataframe is then filtered by the value in the mark cell.

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv('one.csv') # student_id, mark
df2 = pd.read_csv('two.csv') # student_id, name, surname

df1 = df1.join(df2.set_index('student_id'), on='student_id')

df1 = df1.loc[(df1['mark'] == 'five') | (df1['mark'] == 'four')]
```

Comment: My guess is that some of the csv files probably have a space before or after the value for student_id if you are getting duplicate results, thus it is being registered as two different keys when joined. You can call `df1['student_id'] = df1['student_id'].str.strip()` and the same for df2 before calling `join` in order to strip all leading or trailing white space.

Answer (score 0):

You can just read both csv's as a dataframe and join them.

```
import pandas as pd
df_1 = pd.read_csv("csv_1")
df_2 = pd.read_csv("csv_2")
df_1 = df_1.join(df_2)
df_1.to_csv("new_csv")
```

The result will be a csv file with appended columns. If line 1 of csv_1 and line 1 of csv_2 refer to the same thing (person, object, ad_id...) then it can be used without problems.

**Edit:**
If both cvs's are index the rows by student_id, then the easiest way is to include taht when loading the dataframes:

```
import pandas as pd
df_1 = pd.read_csv("csv_1", index_col = "student_id")
df_2 = pd.read_csv("csv_2", index_col = "student_id")
df_1 = df_1.join(df_2)
df_1.to_csv("new_csv")
```

Comment: `columns overlap but no suffix specified: Index(['studentId'], dtype='object')`

Comment: that happens when columns have the same name.... If both contain the same information you can just use df.drop('studentId').

Comment: You can get more details in the documentation:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html

Comment: Another option is to use ```pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)``` which doesn't tend to do as much fancy joining of the two dataframes, it can be handy when you just want to paste two dataframes together (i.e they don't share any columns or data). Changing the axis value to 0 or 1 governs weather pandas puts the two dataframes next to each other or on top of one another.